# AWK -- How to assign a variable's value from matching regex which comes later?

Tags: variables, awk

While I have this **awk script**,

```
/regex2/{
var = $1}

/regex1/{
print var}
```

which I executed over **input file**:

```
regex1

This should be assigned as variable regex2
```

I got no printed output. The desired output is: "This" to be printed out.

I might then think to utilize BEGIN:

```
BEGIN{
/regex2/
var = $1}

/regex1/{
print var}
```

But apparently BEGIN cannot accommodate regex matching function. Any suggestion to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would achieve the desired result:

```
awk '/regex2/ { print $1 }'
```

Otherwise, you'll need to read the file twice and perform something like the following. It will store the last occurrence of `/regex2/` in `var`. Upon re-reading the file, it will print `var` for each occurrence of `/regex1/`. Note that you'll get an empty line in the output and the keyword 'This' on a newline:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /regex2/ { var = $1; next } /regex1/ { print var }' file.txt{,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this sort of thing is done with a flag:

```
/regex1/ { f = 1 }
f && /regex2/ { var = $1; f = 0 }
```